# Какой babel preset подключить вместо @babel/stage-0

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel

@babel/stage-x удалили в верcии Babel 7+
Какой пресет подключить в .babelrc что бы работал import/export из es6
Я использую webpack 4

```
.babelrc
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "targets": {
                "node": "current",
            },
            "useBuiltIns": 'entry'
        }],
        "@babel/react"
    ]
}
```

Ошибка 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Соответствие устаревших stage пресетам](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-stage-0#babelpreset-stage-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `@babel/preset-env` с удобной опцией `"useBuiltIns": "usage"` и не париться на счет полифилов, babel все сделает за Вас.

С этой опцией babel добавляет импорт полифилов на основе использования в преобразованном коде. Например, если вы используете `Object.assign` в своем коде, соответствующий polyfill будет автоматически импортирован если ваша целевая среда не поддерживает его.

Если вы создаете библиотеку или веб-компонент вместо приложения, Вы, вероятно, захотите установить значение `useBuiltIns` как `false` и позволить потребительскому приложению отвечать за полифилы.

Обратите внимание, что обнаружение использования не применяется к вашим зависимостям (которые по умолчанию исключены `cli-plugin-babel`). Если для одной из ваших зависимостей нужны полисы, у вас есть несколько вариантов:

- Если зависимость отправляет код ES5 и явно перечисляет требуемые полифилы: вы можете предварительно включить необходимые полисы, используя опцию polyfills для этой предварительной настройки.
- Если зависимость отправляет код ES5, но использует функции ES6 + без явного указания какие полифилы нужны: используйте `"useBuiltIns": "entry"`, а затем добавьте `import '@babel/polyfill'` в ваш входной файл (главный). Это будет импортировать **ВСЕ** полифилы на основе ваших целевых показателей какие браузеры поддерживать, так что вам больше не нужно будет беспокоиться о полисах с зависимостями, но, скорее всего, увеличит ваш окончательный размер пакета с помощью некоторых неиспользуемых полифилов.

Вот таким будет конфиг:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Подробнее [тут](https://new.babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env.html#usebuiltins-usage).

Также для Babel 7.x желательно использовать файл конфига `babel.config.js` вместо `.babelrc`: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files